Printing a parking receipt using C Code and currently trying to improve a couple of things
I'm currently making a code that prints out a parking fare for customers. I'm pretty much done with most of the code, but i need help with a couple touches to make the output look better. Like how the minutes has an empty space in the tens placement if you only input 1 digit number, so i want it to have a default 0 in case there isn't a second number.
And i also want to make it so that the "type of vehicle" output prints out Car/Bus/Truck instead of only C/B/T.
This is the output i get:
Type of vehicle? (C - Car, B - Bus, T - Truck): C
Hour vehicle entered lot? (1 - 24): 6
Minute vehicle entered lot? (1 - 60): 2
Hour vehicle left lot? (1 - 24): 9
Minute vehicle left lot? (1 - 60): 3


---PARKING LOT CHARGE---

TYPE OF VEHICLE: C
TIME-IN:            6: 2
TIME-OUT:           9: 3
                 -------
PARKING TIME:       3: 1
ROUNDED TOTAL:         3
                 -------
TOTAL CHARGE:     $0.00

I want the output to look like this:
Type of vehicle? (C - Car, B - Bus, T - Truck): C
Hour vehicle entered lot? (1 - 24): 6
Minute vehicle entered lot? (1 - 60): 2
Hour vehicle left lot? (1 - 24): 9
Minute vehicle left lot? (1 - 60): 3


---PARKING LOT CHARGE---

TYPE OF VEHICLE: Car
TIME-IN:            6:02
TIME-OUT:           9:03
                 -------
PARKING TIME:       3:01
ROUNDED TOTAL:         3
                 -------
TOTAL CHARGE:     $0.00

Here is my whole code.
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {

    int hourIn, minuteIn, hourOut, minuteOut, parkH, parkM, rounded;
    float charge;
    char type;

    printf("Type of vehicle? (C - Car, B - Bus, T - Truck): ");
    scanf("%c", &type);
    printf("Hour vehicle entered lot? (1 - 24): ");
    scanf("%d", &hourIn);
    printf("Minute vehicle entered lot? (1 - 60): ");
    scanf("%d", &minuteIn);
    printf("Hour vehicle left lot? (1 - 24): ");
    scanf("%d", &hourOut);
    printf("Minute vehicle left lot? (1 - 60): ");
    scanf("%d", &minuteOut);

    if (minuteOut < minuteIn) {
        minuteOut += 60;
        hourOut -= 1;
        parkH = hourOut - hourIn;
        parkM = minuteOut - minuteIn;
    }
    else {
        parkH = hourOut - hourIn;
        parkM = minuteOut - minuteIn;
    }
   
    if (parkM >= 50) {
        rounded = parkH + 1;
    }
    else {
        rounded = parkH;
    }

    switch (type) {
        case 'C':
            if (rounded <= 3) {
                charge = rounded * 0;
            }
            else {
                charge = (rounded - 3) * 1.50;
            }
            break;
        case 'T':
            if (rounded <= 2) {
                charge = rounded * 1;
            }
            else {
                charge = (rounded - 2) * 2.30 + 2;
            }
            break;
        case 'B':
            if (rounded <= 1) {
                charge = rounded * 2;
            }
            else {
                charge = (rounded * 2) *  3.70 + 2;
            }
            break;
    }
   
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("---PARKING LOT CHARGE---\n\n");
    printf("TYPE OF VEHICLE: %c\n", type);
    printf("TIME-IN:           %2d:%2d\n", hourIn, minuteIn);
    printf("TIME-OUT:          %2d:%2d\n", hourOut, minuteOut);
    printf("                 -------\n");
    printf("PARKING TIME:      %2d:%2d\n", parkH, parkM);
    printf("ROUNDED TOTAL:        %2d\n", rounded);
    printf("                 -------\n");
    printf("TOTAL CHARGE:     $%-3.2f\n", charge);
   
    return 0;
}


Try %02d format spec. to zero-pad.

printf("TYPE OF VEHICLE: "); switch (type) { default: puts("ERROR"); break; case 'C': puts("Car"); break; case 'B': puts("Bus"); break; case 'T': puts("Truck"); break; }

...for the minutes. Note the the total charge will overflow the field width with %-3.2f even for single-digit dollars. The 3 applies to the whole value an dit's pointless. You can just use %.2f to position it as shown.

@Mark David Semorio, Curious, who or what text suggested using  float for float charge; rather than double?

BTW: Instead of using scanf for user input I recommend to use fgets and sscanf. Check the return value of scanf or sscanf to find out if the conversion was successful.

Instead of scattering the hourly rates around as hard coded values, put them in an array. It's also unclear whether the + 2 is part of the charging rate, making such code difficult to maintain. You could also use an array of struct to hold the variable and/or fixed fee and the vehicle type's name.

@mark 1) Rather than if (minuteOut < minuteIn) ... to determine the elapsed time, a more common approach would use: int delta_minutes =  (hourOut - hourIn)*60 + MinuteOut - MinuteIn; and then use delta_minutes (with some provision for hourOut < hourIn.  e.g the next day) for subsequent rate calculations.  2) Strange to see 1-60, 1-24 rather than 0-59,0-23.

If you park overnight, this code owes you money? That is really convenient...

And if you park for several days you will at maximum pay for 24 hours, since it only takes hours and minutes into account.

i forgot to mention this in the post, but i am only allowed to use switch, if-else, or maybe a bit of loop since those are the things my teacher have discussed. so things like arrays and such are not an option for me since i haven't learned it yet hahahahah.

@chux-ReinstateMonica i was the one who made the decision to use float for the variable charge since it will result with a decimal. double and float are the same right? it's just that double can hold more numbers than float.

@Neil hahahah sorry about that, i forgot to add a code when they park past midnight. will add it later :D. completely missed it hahahahaha

@isrnick the code is suppose to print an output saying the car got towed since it parked past midnight, i completely forgot to add it cause i was using most of my braincells making this scuffed code hahahahaha

@WeatherVane i will try using that, ty for the suggestion!

Note the double and float are not the same. The float is inferior and should only be used for a very good reason that you can cite, and double is the 'natural' floating point type in C. For example this value 1.23 has type double unless forced to be a float value with suffix, e.g. 1.23f.

@chux-ReinstateMonica aaaaah using 1-59 and 1-23 makes a lot more sense. thank you for pointing this out hahahaahaha. it's the obvious things that i always miss out and make mistakes with.

@WeatherVane aight i'll go and change it to double, and will use double for future codes. thanks a lot for explaining the differences between the two!

@chux-ReinstateMonica w8, actually i need to leave it as 24, since the instructions says that the vehicle will be towed past midnight. i'll change the minute part tho.

I also have another question. the instruction also says to round the parking time up to the next hour before calculating the charge. i don't rly get what this means, does it mean to round it up if minutes >= 50?

I would guess that any time period from say 1:01 to 1:59 will be charged as 2 hours – which is what real car parks typically do (apart from a grace period between paying and leaving).

I think we've all made similar mistakes, that's why we're on the lookout for them. Are the specifications very strict? Can we see? (In particular, the method of rounding seems very arbitrary.) I would avoid using float or double, instead minutes and cents. May be more suited for code review.

@Neil for the rounding up part, it only says that since there are no fractional charges, we are supposed to round the parking hour/s to the next hour before calculating the charge. We're also told to use switch to select which rate to charge the user. There's also the part where it says making multiple functions besides main is a common approach to this. idk how to make another function since we haven't rly tried it yet.

@WeatherVane i might just go with that, can't rly think of anything else. And i don't have a car to park so I have no experience with it whatsoever hahahaha

Immediately converting all times to a usable internal format (minutes since 00:00 as int, perhaps?), calculating, then back-transforming them to output, 3 independent problems, may be easier than one huge problem to test and debug.
